# Passing values from TableViewCell to Detail View

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Much like some of the other posts I've sifted through, here's the part where I say I'm new to Swift. I have an app that allows you to store an image and data (via Core Data) for your favorite movies. This part works fine. I'm able to create a new post and view it via my tableViewCell. The part I'm having an issue with, it displaying the image and data on a details page after tapping on a cell.

I've read other postings and articles on the subject and I'm pretty sure I need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue`, but I'm just not understanding what I should be adding and how. Part of the problem is being new to Swift. See below for details and my code. Let me know if you need more details. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Would also love a link to some helpful reading material on the subject, if you know of any. In addition to the files below, I also have one for creating a post (PostMovieVC.swift) and one for my custom cell (MovieCell.swift).

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var movies = [Movie]()

var storeMovieTitle: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    fetchAndSetResults()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func fetchAndSetResults() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movie")

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        self.movies = results as! [Movie]
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MovieCell") as? MovieCell {

        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(movie)
        return cell
    } else {
        return MovieCell()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let movie = movies[indexPath.row]

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowMovieDetail" {
        let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MovieDetailsVC
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
        detailsVC.passedTitle = storeMovieTitle

    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 169.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return movies.count
}

}
```

**MovieDetailsVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MovieDetailsVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var showMovieImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var showTitleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showSeenWithLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showQuoteLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showLinkLbl: UILabel!

var passedMovieImg: UIImageView!
var passedTitle: String?
var passedSeenWith: String?
var passedQuote: String?
var passedLink: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    showMovieImg.image = passedMovieImg
    showTitleLbl.text = passedTitle
    showSeenWithLbl.text = passedSeenWith
    showQuoteLbl.text = passedQuote
    showLinkLbl.text = passedLink

}

@IBAction func closeBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

}
```

Comment: Did you add segue between ViewController and MoviewDetailsVC on TableViewCell click?!

Comment: you need to create segue between firstviewcontroller to details view controller. save you indexPath.row and after that use that index path row value in prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, yep, I created a "Show" segue from my main VC to the MovieDetailsVC.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by updating my code as follows:

Updated prepareForSegue func as follows:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // get the segue identifier
    if segue.identifier == "ShowMovieDetail" {
        // get a reference for the destination view controller and the selected cell indexPath
        if let MovieDetailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? MovieDetailsVC, let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {


            let movie = movies[indexPath.row]
            MovieDetailsVC.movie = movie
        }

    }
}
```

Removed the following code from MovieDetailsVC:

```
    var passedMovieImg: UIImageView!
    var passedTitle: String?
    var passedSeenWith: String?
    var passedQuote: String?
    var passedLink: String?
```

Replaced the above with:

```
    var movie: Movie?
```

Updated viewWillAppear as follows:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

       showMovieImg.image = movie?.getMovieImg()
       showTitleLbl.text = movie!.title
       showSeenWithLbl.text = movie!.seenwith
       showQuoteLbl.text = movie!.quote
       showLinkLbl.text = movie!.trailer

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

in movie detailVC you declare one variable of type array or dictionary, initialize that array in tableview didsselect in ViewController , in viewdidload of moviewdetailvc you can use those details

Comment: Plaese give me reason for downvoting to this answer